# Check Value from an Input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to match the input number to a randomly generated number.  If the two number's match, I want it to display as correct.  What am I missing or not doing correctly?

```js
var int = getRandomInt(3);
var number = document.getElementsByClassName(".idk");
var clickButton = document.querySelector("#me");



function getRandomInt(num){
  var result = Math.floor(Math.random()* num);
  return result;
} 

clickButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  getRandomInt(3);
  if(int == number){
    alert("mayber");
  } else {
    alert("maybe not");
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
    <input class="idk" type="number">
    <button id="me">Click Me!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: The variable called `number` in your code represents a collection of HTML elements. Therefore it will never be equal to a numeric value

Comment: You probably want to give your input an ID instead of a class, then use getElementById to get the specific element and then get its "value" property and then parse it to an int before comparing it to anything else. And you need to do all of that inside your "click" event otherwise you'll end up with stale data.

Comment: Also in the click event you need to write `int = getRandomInt(3)` - right now you are not assigning the result the function to anything so it will never generate a new number

Comment: What do *you* think it's not doing correctly?  What efforts have *you* made to debug your own code?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty when I would show an alert to see if it was comparing the int and the number variables and it kept popping up the "else" statement.  I tried using different selectors as well

Comment: @ADyson how come I have seen examples where the function is called from a variable outside of a function and then reused in a click event?

Comment: I'm not saying that isn't possible or even useful, I'm saying it's no good if you need to value to change each time the button is clicked. I was assuming you wanted to generate a new random number on each click. But maybe you don't? However you definitely need to get the latest value of the input box on each click, otherwise you'll only ever see what the value was when the page originally loaded

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few issues in the code above. I have updated the snippet with comments to explain.

```js
// return the first and matching instance - id should be unique in your html
var number = document.querySelector("#idk");
var clickButton = document.querySelector("#me");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
}

clickButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  // get the target and made the variable name change as "int" is a reserved word in JS
  var target = getRandomInt(1, 3);
  // we need to convert the string value to int and do a === comparison
  if(target === parseInt(number.value)){
    alert("maybe");
  } else {
    alert("maybe not");
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
    <input id="idk" class="idk" type="number">
    <button id="me">Click Me!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: I'm still learning; how is the "parseInt" being used if the input's value isn't a string?

Comment: the value from the input is a string at this point, you can test using alert(typeof number.value); its best to always use === comparisons in JS

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score -1):

Your code has 3 issues

1. You have added ".idk" . It's actually "idk" only. you don't need to specify a dot in getElementsByClassName
2. You want to get value from a single input element. So you can use `document.querySelector(".idk")` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName(".idk");`
3. You are selecting only the Element. Not the element value. You can do that via `if (int == number.value)`

Comment: Ok.  Makes a little more sense now.  How is the ".getElementsByClassName()" different from the query selector if I only have one class with the name .idk?

Comment: querySelector actually returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned. getElementsByClassName collects all elements that matches as an Objected Array. So to select the first one, its probably better to use querySelector.